# create graph in spark-graphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have spark 2.3 and I use scala with sbt. I want to create a graph in graphx.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import spark.implicits._

object ne {

        def main(args: Array[String]){

        val spark = SparkSession
                        .builder
                        .appName("Scala-Northern-E")
                        .getOrCreate()

val vertexArray = Array(
  (1L, ("Alice", 28)),
  (2L, ("Bob", 27)),
  (3L, ("Charlie", 65)),
  (4L, ("David", 42)),
  (5L, ("Ed", 55)),
  (6L, ("Fran", 50))
  )
val edgeArray = Array(
  Edge(2L, 1L, 7),
  Edge(2L, 4L, 2),
  Edge(3L, 2L, 4),
  Edge(3L, 6L, 3),
  Edge(4L, 1L, 1),
  Edge(5L, 2L, 2),
  Edge(5L, 3L, 8),
  Edge(5L, 6L, 3)
  )
val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(vertexArray)
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = spark.saprkContext.parallelize(edgeArray)

  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
[error] /home/azade/data (3rd copy)/spark-ne.scala:10:8: not found: object spark
[error] import spark.implicits._
[error]        ^
[error] /home/azade/data (3rd copy)/spark-ne.scala:42:37: value saprkContext is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
[error] val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = spark.saprkContext.parallelize(edgeArray)
[error]                                     ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Jul 10, 2018 8:22:11 PM
```

Why do I get this error and what should I do for that?
what should I import for support `sc.parallelize`?

Comment: Are you using spark shell?

Comment: no, i want to run my code with sbt. it works in spark shell

Comment: Probably you are missing `sparkContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `sc` add

```
spark.sparkContext
```

Comment: There is typo in your code `spark.saprkContext` instead of `spark.sparkContext`
Correct the typo and remove the import statement, I mentioned